# MPI job "consuming" cgroup pids

Tags: mpi, cgroups

I have a processing job which uses MPI for parallelisation, but is (in this case) running in a single host. Each time I run a job, it "consumes" a number of cgroup "pids". Specifically each time I run the job,

`/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.current`

Increases (not surprisingly) but when the job completes, it returns to larger value than it started. The increase in `pids.current` equals the number of MPI processes launched. My job launches about 30 MPI processes and I have to run it hundreds of time, so `pids.current` rapidly increases to a number where it is larger than `pids.max` and no further processes for the specific user can be created. As a workaround I have been increasing `pids.max`, but that is a pretty poor solution.

I launch the job with `mpirun` and the cgroup setup is default for Debian.

I have demonstrated the same problem with a unrelated "mpi-helloworld" program from

`https://github.com/wesleykendall/mpitutorial`

so I am confident it is not my software. I have an identical machine wrt hardware, running the same Linux kernel/distribution which was setup by someone else which does *not* show this problem. One other machine (different hardware, same Linux kernel) also does not show the problem.

I can find no reference anywhere online of someone seeing the same problem.

I am running:

> Debian GNU/Linux 9
>
> Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u5 (2018-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
>
> libopenmpi-dev                            2.0.2-2
> libopenmpi2:amd64                         2.0.2-2
> openmpi-bin                               2.0.2-2
> openmpi-common                            2.0.2-2

Can anyone suggest what is wrong or where to look?

Comment: How do you run your application ? Do you use a resource manager ? Who created the cgroup ?

Comment: Gilles - I updated the question

Comment: The level of details you provided suggests you should ask that someone else who did the setup on the other machine. Meanwhile, you can `sysctl -a` (preferably as root) on both boxes and try to spot some differences.

Comment: Gilles - I have already spoken to them. This is all default setups.